# Problem with filtering and sorting a ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, sorting, filtering

I have a ListView with a customized filter and a customized sort Comparator. Both of filtering and sort operations work fine separately. But when I use them altogether I encounter a problem.

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
sortList();
```

I filter my adapter and then I sort it. But filter operation is done at the end in all circumstances.
Why the filter is applied on ListView at the end and how can I sort the list **after** filtering?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself.

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s, new FilterListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
            sortList();
        }
    });
```